Scaling-invariant property of Navier-Stokes equation under Besov spaces
I meet a problem when reading Bahouri, Chemin & Danchin's book Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations.
In page 234, the authors' write in Theorem 5.40 that it $p\in[1,\infty)$, then the system $(GNS_{\nu})$ has a unique solution $u$ in a certain ball in $E_p$, which is a subspace of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+,\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}})$. Here $(GNS_{\nu})$ appears in page 207:
$$
(GNS_{\nu}):\ \begin{cases}
\partial_tu-\nu\Delta u=Q(u,u)\\
u|_{t=0}=u_0
\end{cases}
$$
which generalizes the original 3D Navier-Stokes system appeared in page 204:
$$
(NS_{\nu}):\ \begin{cases}
\partial_tu+\mathrm{div}(u\otimes u)-\nu\Delta u=-\nabla P\\
\mathrm{div}\ u=0\\
u|_{t=0}=u_0
\end{cases}
$$
so Theorem 5.40 also asserts existence of solution of $(NS_{\nu})$ in a certain ball in $E_p$.
The authors use a fixed-point lemma (Lemma 5.5 on page 207) to prove Theorem 5.40, and they claim in page 208 that this approach "requires a Banach space $X$ with a norm invariant under the transformations that preserve the set of global solutions", which in my opinion means that if we define
$$
u_{\lambda}(t,x)=\lambda u(\lambda^2t,\lambda x),
$$
then the norm of $X$ should satisfy:
$$
\|u_{\lambda}\|_X=\|u\|_X.
$$
So the proof of Theorem 5.40 suggests that $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+,\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}})$ should be such a scaling-invariant space. Here comes the problem: How to verify this for any $\lambda>0$? I know if $\lambda=2^N(N\in\mathbb{Z})$, then using homogeneity of $\|\cdot\|_{\dot{B}_{p,r}^s}$(Proposition 2.18 on page 64) we have
$$
\|u_{\lambda}\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+,\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}})}=\|2^N2^{N((-1+\frac{3}{p})-\frac{3}{p})}u(\cdot,\cdot)\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+,\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}})}=\|u\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+,\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}})}.
$$
But when $\lambda\ne2^N$, I don't know how to verify it. Here is what I've tried:
Using definition of $\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}}$: Since
$$
\widehat{u_{\lambda}}(t,\xi)=\lambda^{1-d}\widehat{u}(\lambda^2t,\frac{\xi}{\lambda})
$$
where $d$ is dimension, then
$$
\|\varphi_j\widehat{u_{\lambda}}\|_{L^p_{\xi}}=\lambda^{1-d}\|\varphi_j(\xi)\widehat{u}(\frac{\xi}{\lambda})\|_{L_{\xi}^p}.
$$
Here I'm stuck. If changing variable by $\eta=\xi/\lambda$, then I don't know how to deal with $\widehat{\varphi}_j(\lambda\eta)$. I tried to regard $\widehat{\varphi}_j(\lambda\eta)$ as a new family generated by a new $\varphi$ used to define Besov spaces and to use the fact that $\dot{B}_{p,r}^s$ doesn't depend on the choice of $\varphi$. But I think function $\varphi$ used to define $\dot{B}_{p,d}^s$ should at least satisfy that $\{|x|=1\}\subset\mathrm{supp}\varphi$, which will be broken when $\lambda$ is too big or too small. Also, assuming that $\widehat{\varphi}_j(\lambda\eta)$ makes sense, then
$$
2^{js}\|\varphi_j\widehat{u_{\lambda}}\|_{L_{\xi}^p}=2^{js}\lambda^{1-d+\frac{d}{p}}\|\varphi_j(\lambda\cdot)\widehat{u}(\cdot)\|_{L_{\xi}^p},
$$
I think $\lambda^{1-p+\frac{d}{p}}$ shouldn't be regarded as a constant independent of $2^{js}$, otherwise to meet scaling-invariant property we have $1-p+\frac{d}{p}=0$, which is obviously wrong. But I don't know what's the relationship between $2^{js}$ and $\lambda^{1-p+\frac{d}{p}}$.
Using heat flow characterization of $\dot{B}_{p,\infty}^{-1+\frac{3}{p}}$: I notice that $p>3$ means $-1+\frac{3}{p}<0$, so I tried to use Theorem 2.34 on page 72, which tells the equivalence between $\|u\|_{\dot{B}_{p,r}^{-2s}}$ and $\|\|t^se^{t\Delta}u\|_{L^p}\|_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^+,\frac{dt}{t})}$ when $s>0,(p,r)\in[1,\infty]^2$. I think the $t$ appears in $u_{\lambda}(t,x)$ should be different from $t$ appears here, so I rewrite $u_{\lambda}(t,x)$ as $u_{\lambda}(T,x)$. Using the fact that
$$
(e^{-t|\xi|^2})^{\vee}=t^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{|\xi|^2}{t}},
$$
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|t^se^{t\Delta}u_{\lambda}\|_{L^p}&=[\int (t^s(e^{-t|\xi|^2}\widehat{u_{\lambda}})^{\vee})^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=[\int (t^s(t^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{|\cdot|^2}{t}}*\lambda u(T,\lambda\cdot)))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=\lambda[\int t^{p(s-\frac{d}{2})}(\int e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{t}} u(T,\lambda(x-\eta))d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=\lambda[\int t^{p(s-\frac{d}{2})}(\int \lambda^{-d}e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{\lambda^2t}} u(T,x-\eta)d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=\lambda^{1-d}[\int t^{p(s-\frac{d}{2})}(\int e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{\lambda^2t}} u(T,x-\eta)d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\|t^se^{t\Delta}u_{\lambda}\|_{L^p}\|_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^+,\frac{dt}{t})}&=\lambda^{1-d}\|[\int t^{p(s-\frac{d}{2})}(\int e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{\lambda^2t}} u(T,x-\eta)d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\|_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^+,\frac{dt}{t})}\\
&=\lambda^{1-d}\|t^{s-\frac{d}{2}}[\int (\int e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{\lambda^2t}} u(T,x-\eta)d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\|_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^+,\frac{dt}{t})}\\
&=\lambda^{1-d}\lambda^{d-2s}\|(\lambda^2t)^{s-\frac{d}{2}}[\int (\int e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{\lambda^2t}} u(T,x-\eta)d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\|_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^+,\frac{dt}{t})}\\
&=\lambda^{1-2s}\|t^{s-\frac{d}{2}}[\int (\int e^{-\frac{|\eta|^2}{t}} u(T,x-\eta)d\eta))^pdx]^{\frac{1}{p}}\|_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^+,\frac{dt}{t})}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus scaling-invariant property requires that $s=\frac{1}{2}$, which doesn't fit the result.
I don't know what's wrong here:(,  I'll be grateful if you have any idea.

Your first idea is good. What you do can do is to first write $\lambda=s\cdot \mu$ where $\mu\in 2^N$ and $1\leq s<2$, and write $u_\lambda=(u_s)_{\mu}$. By transitivity, you can show first that $u_s$ and $u$ have comparable norm, and then you can show the same for $(u_s)$ and $(u_s)_\mu$.
This way, you can essentially deal with the cases $\lambda\in 2^{N}$ and $1\leq \lambda<2$ separately. In the first case, as you have showed, the norm remains the same. In the case $1\leq \mu< 2$, you can consider the new system $\hat\phi_j(\lambda\eta)$ and show that this gives an equivalent norm.
The norm is indeed not completely independent of $\lambda$ when defined via discrete summation over the diadic annuli, but its dependence is bounded from above and from below uniformly in $\lambda$. It is possible to define an equivalent norm on the Besov space that is truly scaling invariant in a few different ways, for example considering a continuous version of the Besov norm, or taking the infimum over $\lambda>0$ of the usual Besov norm of $u_\lambda$.

Thank you for your answer! So when $1\le s<2$ we can define new function $\phi$ like $\mathrm{supp}\phi\subset{\frac{3}{8}\le|x|\le\frac{4}{3}}$ to ensure that $\mathrm{supp}\phi(s\cdot)$ still contains ${|x|=1}$, so $\dot{B}_{p,r}^s$ generated by $\phi(s\cdot)$ and that generated by $\phi$ is "same". Am I right?
